# 0 valid codesigning identities after installing IOS developer certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

I logged into the developer page of Apple to create a develoepr certificate.

I followed the instructions on the website and created a certificate request.

I Uploaded the request and I got the message that everything worked.

I look into the Keychain Access application under "My Certificates" and it lists the certificate I just installed but It also states: "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority".

I run the following command in the terminal: "security find-identity -v -p codesigning" and it returns: o valid identities found.

I'm trying since two days to sign the IOS version of my application. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, I gave up on the IOS port because of this and more problems.